# How can get colors in Axis Labels

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I had problems with pivot chart. Apply data labels to my chart, I select the data labels and  open “format data labels” windows, go to numbers tab. Select “custom” and code like this : [black] +0%; [red] -0% to format positive values to black color and format negative values to red color.
So, how to code it in macro excel?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub format_datalabel()

Dim my_series As Series
Dim pt As Point

'change the chart name and update the SeriesCollection number if you have more than 1 series in your chart
Set my_series = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

For Each pt In my_series.Points
    pt.DataLabel.NumberFormat = "[black] +0%; [red] -0%"
Next pt

End Sub
```

Just change the chart name and run the code.
Also if you have more than 1 serries in your chart, you should identify it as well.